# Whether a $2 \times 2$ matrix of rank $1$ has a zero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

"Does $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$ have a zero eigenvalue?"

Well, it would be a funny question to ask if the asker didn't state that he wants us to explain without computing the characteristic polynomial. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: just see the nullity

Comment: See the determinant :).

Answer (score 5):

You know that $$2 = \dim \ker A + \dim {\rm col} \ A.$$

If $\dim {\rm col} \ A = 1$, our hypothesis, then $\dim \ker A = 1$, so we have non zero vectors in $\ker A = \ker(A - 0 \ {\rm Id})$. So yes, $0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: How do you know the equation is true? Why 2? How do you know dim col A = 1? What is dim col A? -> Some of the many questions that can arise. This answer seems too complicated. The OP is likely just beginning linear algebra or has just completed it. Do you have comments on the other answers?

Comment: It is a well known theorem. I, at least, learned it in the context of linear mappings, way before seeing eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The dimension of ${\rm col} \ A$ is $1$ because both columns are linearly dependent, so ${\rm col} \ A$ is just a line, I thought that this was also clear. It was just the first thing that came to my mind. The determinant is also a quick way out of the problem. (and I sure hope that OP knows that he can accept the most helpful answer, it doesn't have to be mine, despite having more upvotes now)

Answer (score 5):

No problem. Just go back to the definition.

$Ax = \lambda x$

Find a $\lambda$ and a nonzero x s.t. the above holds. There are in fact infinitely many since the matrix has a determinant of zero/is singular.

Answer (score 0):

This matrix has determinant $0$. So  the matrix is non invertible, and hence must have $0$ as an eigenvalue. ($A-\lambda I$ is not invertible for $\lambda=0$).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how green exactly you are but the determinate is a very easy way to determine whether a matrix has a 0 eigenvalue.  To take the determinant this is usually illustrated with the matrix below that i will call M.

$M = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$

Where the Det M = ad-cb  if the Det M = 0 we know there is at least one eigenvalue that equals 0. I believe the characteristic polynomial hes refuring to is "$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

or  x + 2y =0

and 2x + 4y =0

you can then use one of these equations to solve for x and sub it into the other ( this is a common grade 11/12 method that i believe hes trying to get you to avoid. with the characteristic polynomial comment.)

Lastly the First method you'd probably be taught in college (before you'd learn what a determinant was) is row operations in this case $R_2 - 2R_1$ ( $R_1$ = row 1 of the matrix ) yields the matrix
$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ now since $R_2$ is a row of all 0's we know we have a 0 eigenvalue. Which i believe most second year courses stop and simply dismiss this as unsolvable?